# Magento API Bulk Update fails due to known bug, but fix doesn't work. PHP

Tags: php, magento

Details are here:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/35347

To summarize -  when using the `rest/default/async/bulk/V1/products` in Magento version 2.4.4 and 2.4.3-p2 to update or delete records in bulk it will fail with an error saying something like:

> TypeError: Argument 3 passed to Magento\Framework\Webapi\ServiceInputProcessor::process() must be of the type array, string given, called in .../vendor/magento/module-webapi-async/Controller/Rest/Asynchronous/InputParamsResolver.php on line 156 and defined in .../vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ServiceInputProcessor.php:172

I'm using Magento version 2.4.3-p2 but the fix doesn't seem to work. I modified the lines as suggested (even though my file isn't identical, perhaps its a 2.4.4 version?)

The commit adds 2 lines and removes one. It doesn't look like its doing much to be honest, but either way it doesn't change anything. Same error.

Any advice would be appreciated. My code:

```
$samplePayload = '[
    {
        "sku": "test123",
        "product": {
            "price": 1049.24
        }
    }
]';

$url = 'https://example.com/rest/default/async/bulk/V1/products/bySku';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $samplePayload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

Comment: Have you tried asking on [magento.se]?

Comment: take a look at the https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/35347#issuecomment-1125164447 which mention that only the commit wont solve it at 2.4.3-p2, comment below this one provides additional patch

Comment: I just posed in Magento, sorry wasn't aware of it. Regarding the patch, I did try that but it said my system already had it installed.